# While resolving: codelyzer@0.0.28 npm ERR! Found: tslint@6.1.3 npm ERR! node_modules/tslint npm ERR! optional tslint@"6.1.3" from the root project

Tags: angular

I was trying to add angular elements in angular 15.0.4 project and found the following error

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are conflicting peer dependencies of tslint , you might have to share your package.json for more info

Alternatively you can also use "npm i --legacy-peer-deps" but it might broke some dependency

Alternatively you can use eslint -

tslint and codelyzer has been deprecated from angular 11 ,
You should use eslint in angular 15
For more info about tslint , codelyzer and eslint you can refer -

Migration guide  - https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#migrating-from-codelyzer-and-tslint

typescript-eslint - https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint

angular-eslint - https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint

tslint-to-eslint-config - https://github.com/typescript-eslint/tslint-to-eslint-config